# How can I add the result of an asynchronous method to the Glimpse Broker?

Tags: c#, async-await, glimpse

Title says it all really.

I'd like to put some information about the result of an `async` method into the Glimpse Message Broker. I tried to use `Task.ContinueWith` for this:

```
        task.ContinueWith((t) =>
        {                
            var response = t.Result;
            var message = new ExternalRequestMessage
            {
                Url = url,
                Method = method,
                RequestBody = requestBody,
                WasAsync = true,
                StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                Status = response.StatusCode.ToString(),
                WasSuccess = response.IsSuccessStatusCode,
                Fault = response.Fault,
            };

            if (messageBroker != null)
            {
                messageBroker.Publish(message);
            }
        });
```

This code executes without issue, and I can put a breakpoint on and follow the code through so I know it executes.

However, when I come to read the messages back off the broker, they are not there. eg, a breakpoint on the tab code below shows that the messages are not there:

```
    public override object GetData(ITabContext context)
    {
        return context.GetMessages<ExternalRequestMessage>();
    }
```

Additionally- I am putting `ExternalRequestMessage`s onto the broker from a synchronous context, and those messages are showing up in the tab as expected.

Can anyone shed some light on what's going on here?

**Edit:** I should add that I am using `ContinueWith` as I don't want the app to wait on the result just to add the message to the broker, so just using `task.Result` is not an option.

Comment: Using `Task.Result` with `async-await` is rarelly an option.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint in your continuation and debugging it? Perhaps its throwing an exception?

Comment: Yes I've done that. The code executes without issue. No exceptions are thrown. I'm pretty sure this is a Glimpse issue, or some sort of issue with the scope of the message broker when running on multiple threads.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple instances of your broker due to threading issues.

Comment: Well that's my hunch, but I'm only guessing.I'm hoping someone with more experience with Glimpse can confirm these suspicions, and maybe even supply a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out-

My `web.config` file had

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Glimpse:DisableAsyncSupport" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

Removing this value or setting it to false resolves the issue.